# Win32 Rebar : Issue with myRebar.cbSize occurred after migrating from visual studio 6 to visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-studio-6

I'm trying to migrate fully working win32 code on visual studio 6 to visual studio 2010. It seems there is some problem with Rebar. Below are my code that working fine on visual studio 6.

```
HWND            hwndRebar = NULL;
REBARINFO       rbi;
REBARBANDINFO   rbbi;
HWND            hwndChild;
RECT            rc;
LPSTR           lpszTemp;
UINT            nHeight;

hwndRebar = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, 
                            REBARCLASSNAME, 
                            NULL,
                            WS_VISIBLE |
                            WS_BORDER | 
                            WS_OVERLAPPED | 
                            WS_CHILD | 
                            WS_CLIPCHILDREN | 
                            WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | 
                            RBS_VARHEIGHT | 
                            RBS_BANDBORDERS | 
                            RBS_DBLCLKTOGGLE |
                            RBS_AUTOSIZE |
                            RBS_REGISTERDROP |
                            CCS_TOP |
                            CCS_NODIVIDER | 
                            CCS_NOPARENTALIGN |
                            0,
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            200, 
                            m_info.cyTB, 
                            hwndParent, 
                            (HMENU)IDC_REBAR, 
                            g_hInst, 
                            NULL);

if(!hwndRebar) 
    return FALSE;

rbi.cbSize  = sizeof(rbi);
rbi.fMask   = RBIM_IMAGELIST;
rbi.himl    = NULL;
if(!SendMessage(hwndRebar, RB_SETBARINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&rbi))
    return FALSE;

//add a band that contains a button
hwndChild = CreateMainToolbar(hwndRebar);

if(!hwndChild)
    return FALSE;

GetClientRect(hwndChild, &rc);

ZeroMemory(&rbbi, sizeof(rbbi));
rbbi.cbSize       = sizeof(REBARBANDINFO);
rbbi.fMask        = RBBIM_SIZE | 
                        RBBIM_CHILD | 
                        RBBIM_CHILDSIZE | 
                        RBBIM_ID | 
                        RBBIM_STYLE | 
                        0;
rbbi.cxMinChild   = rc.right;
rbbi.cyMinChild   = MYICON_CY + EXTRA_PIXELS;
rbbi.cyMaxChild   = TallestBtn(hwndChild);
rbbi.cyChild      = m_info.fTextLabels ? rbbi.cyMaxChild : rbbi.cyMinChild;
rbbi.cyIntegral   = rbbi.cyMaxChild - rbbi.cyMinChild;
rbbi.cx           = 100;
rbbi.fStyle       = RBBS_CHILDEDGE | 
                        RBBS_VARIABLEHEIGHT |
                        ((m_info.windows & WND_TOOLBAR) ? 0 : RBBS_HIDDEN) | 
                        0;
rbbi.wID          = IDC_TOOLBAR;
rbbi.hwndChild    = hwndChild;

// SendMessage FAILED on visual studio 2010. But worked on visual studio 6.
if(!SendMessage(hwndRebar, RB_INSERTBAND, (WPARAM)-1, (LPARAM)(LPREBARBANDINFO)&rbbi))
{
    int i = GetLastError(); // --> i = 6 (invalid handle)
    return FALSE;
}
```

I have try run the code in both visual studio 6 and 2010 and make some comparison. I found that on visual 6, the value of **sizeof(REBARBANDINFO)** is **80** and on visual studio 2010 it is **100**. So I did tried an experiment by hard code value on visual studio 2010 to 80. Then sendMessage was successful but the UI inside that rebar is not visible on window.
Can anyone please help me with this problem? 
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Is it a good idea if i replaced **sizeof(REBARBANDINFO)** with **REBARBANDINFOW_V6_SIZE** instead of hard-coding value 80?

Comment: The 100 size is due to new fields added in Vista. If you are running on XP, then the Vista structure is not supported. You need to set your windows version properly before including windows.h.

Comment: @RaymondChen: sorry, i dont understand. when i run the program with visual studio 6 (on window 7) it works. But when run on same OS with visual 2010 it didn't work. Can you please tell me how to set window version?

Comment: Simply set _WIN32_WINNT to the correct value.